# HAXM not installing.. The system requirements are not satisfied

Tags: android-studio, intel, virtualization, failed-installation, haxm

While installing Android Studio, I got the error that HAXM didn't install.. so i tried installing haxm using the solutions provided in stackoverflow, youtube etc.. but its not working.

I have enabled virtualization(screenshot) etc.. still this error. [I have intel i5 11th gen, 16GB RAM, Windows 11]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it is showing vmx supported : no in your screenshot, check virtualization is supported on not by your processor (just google your processor series and look for specs)
if it supports
see virtualization is enabled or not quick check : open task manager, click performance tab it will show virtualization is enabled or not

disable Hyper-V

follow this guide

[Configure hardware acceleration for the Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows)

Comment: yes the virtualization is enabled(i've added the screenshot), and also, i am not able to disable Hyper-V, there is no option of it in the turn windows feature on/off where it should have been.

Comment: in windows features disable : virtual machine platform, windows hypervisor platform and windows sandbox(if listed) than restart system and try installing HAXM again